# How to create a self iterating, conditional Select Statement in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i create a self iterating query to concatenate all Name's Columns from an ID, find a refID matching the id passed in, and repeating the above sequence.

```
id  Name    refID 

34  Name1   37

37  Name2   0

253 Name3   34

254 Name4   0

272 Name5   0

273 Name6   0
```

[image]

**So if I passed in the initial id of `37` , the spit out should be `Name2`, (`34` has a `refID`  of `37` therefore) `Name1`, (`253` has a `refID` of `34` therefore) `Name3`. `253` doesn't have any `refID's` so stop. `Result = Name2, Name1, Name3`.**

We also only want the query to start looking if the id's refID was initially 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a recursive query. What you got there is comparable to a tree structure. 
Also you want your result to be just one row if i understand you right.

On what Database are you working? As far as i know MySql does not support recursive queries.  In SQL Server you can achieve this with that something like this:

```
with ref(id, refId, name ) as(
  select id, refId, cast((name + ' ') as varchar(max))
  from test
  where id = 37
  union all
  select t.id, t.refId, cast((r.name + t.name + ' ') as varchar(max))
  from test t
  join ref r 
  on r.id = t.refId
)
select top 1 name from ref
order by len(name) desc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7961/6/0)

I hope this helps. ;)

Comment: I do have 1 question, how can i use that within the already written select statement say within the select im setting a { descrition = ( with statment you wrote )} for an insert?

Comment: You want to insert the result into another table? It should be possible to replace the select statement after the with clause with an insert statement. Like INSERT INTO T (C) SELECT top 1 name from ...

Comment: Yeah i actually was able to place the with statement infront of the insert command then using the select statement of the `ref` within the insert command, and it worked out freakishly awesome, thanks for your help